# How to put a label at the beginning of an arrow?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows, labels

I came with the following code to display the graph below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
   actor/.style={
     rectangle,
     draw=black,
     minimum size=10mm
   },
   arrow/.style={
     -latex,
     thick,
     shorten <=2pt,
     shorten >=2pt
   }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm and 20mm]
      \node (A)[actor] {A};
      \node (B)[actor,right=of A] {B};
      \node (C)[actor, right=of B] {C};
      \node (Fake) [right=of C] {};
      \node [right=of A,  xshift=-20mm, yshift=2mm] {1};
      \draw[arrow] (A) -- node[font=\small, auto] {$200/s$} (B);
      \draw[arrow] (B) -- node[font=\small, auto] {$100/s$} (C);
      \draw[arrow] (C) -- node[font=\small, auto] {$100/s$} (Fake);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

As you can see I used a **dirty hack** to place the "1" value on top of the beginning of the arrow between A and B. How can I do this properly ?

Comment: please add a minimum working example.

Comment: sorry, it should be ok now

Comment: one more thing, I just saw that my post was edited by @egreg to have proper indentation. is there any automatic way to have this ?

Comment: @ManuelSelva No, there's no automatic way. I feel that good indentation helps in reading the code, so I took the liberty to fix some of the spacings

Comment: @egreg and I thank you for doing it, because I was to lazy to do it myself. My first version was properly indented, but adding the code around to have a minimum working example break this indentation. The code statement of XXXoverflow.com sites is really hard to use.

Comment: If you want to beautify your code, you may use latexindent by @cmhughes: https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can to this with `node[pos=x]` where x is in the range between 0 and 1 for a node placement on the way between beginning and ending of a path. You can choose higher values to move it even before/after that.

If you want it higher/lower you can give above an argument (`above =  x`, `left`, `right`,... also).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
   actor/.style={
     rectangle,
     draw=black,
     minimum size=10mm
   },
   arrow/.style={
     -latex,
     thick,
     shorten <=2pt,
     shorten >=2pt
   }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, thick]

\node[actor] (1) {A};
\node[actor] (2) [right of=1] {B};
\node[actor] (3) [right of=2] {C};
\node[] (4) [right of=3] {};

\draw[arrow]    (1) to node[pos=0.1,above]{1}node [font=\small,above] {$200/s$} (2);
\draw[arrow]    (2) to node [font=\small,above] {$100/s$} (3);
\draw[arrow]    (3) to node [font=\small,above] {$100/s$} (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, all I needed and I have to learn how to search in tikz documentation: "16.8 Placing Nodes on a Line or Curve Explicitly"